# How to use Url.Action to get current url with additional parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, url.action

I've language based routes which works great with `Url.RouteUrl`,

```
[Route("products", Name = "Products_en")] 
[Route("produkte", Name = "Products_de")] 
public ActionResult Products(int page = 1) { 
   return View() 
}
```

On view side, I have a shared view, so I need to create current route with page parameter,

This is what I've tried,

```
Url.Action(null, new { page = 2 })
```

But this generate the url with the first route, not current.

Let's say if user is on the page `example.com/produkte`, but second page url is generated as `example.com/products?page=2`

How can I get the second page url with the current(right) route?

Comment: What happens if you do `Url.Action(RouteData.Values["controller"], new { page = 2 });`?  RiouteData may not exist on the WebPageView so you may have to create it in the controller and pass it in a viewmodel to the view.